Python 3.7 equivalent of `importlib.resources.files`
I have an application that unfortunately does not support Python past 3.7. I have some code I'm trying to port (from Python 3.12) back to Python 3.7 that uses importlib.resources.files to get the path to some non-Python resources that are included in the package:
def _get_file (filename: str) -> bytes:
    """given a resource filename, return its contents"""
    res_path = importlib.resources.files("name.of.my.package")
    with importlib.resources.as_file(res_path) as the_path:
        page_path = os.path.join(the_path, filename)
        with open(page_path, "rb") as f:
            return f.read()

It seems like importlib.resources doesn't have a files() in Python 3.7.
What is the Python 3.7 compatible equivalent of this code?

Maybe the backport has what you need. This is an "official" library, written by the same authors as importlib.resources in the standard library, so for most parts it is also the exact same code. https://pypi.org/project/importlib-resources/

I'm not confident enough to write it up as an answer yet, but based on the documentation I think you want either return importlib.resources.read_text("name.of.my.package", filename) or with importlib.resources.path("name.of.my.package", filename) as f:  return f.read()

@sinoroc That worked; installed it and import importlib_resources and replace importlib.resources with importlib_resources. If you want to post it as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks!

Good. You can write as an answer and accept it yourself, no worries.

I was able to get this working with the importlib-resources backport as per sinoroc's comment.
pip install importlib-resources

And then using it like:
import importlib_resources

def _get_file (filename: str) -> bytes:
    """given a resource filename, return its contents"""
    res_path = importlib_resources.files("name.of.my.package")
    with importlib_resources.as_file(res_path) as the_path:
        page_path = os.path.join(the_path, filename)
        with open(page_path, "rb") as f:
            return f.read()

So really the only code change was find/replacing importlib.resources with importlib_resources, it's just a drop-in replacement.
Note the PyPi page says Python >= 3.8 for this package, but it seems to work fine on 3.7, at least for the above usage.
